# Redirect only search link with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want redirect my all search query only to another domain post like

`domainA.com/?s=this+is+source+link+
domainA.com/?s=+this+is+source+link+
domainA.com/?s=this+is+source+link+3
domainA.com/?s=this+is+source+link+4`

will go same page on another domain

```
domainB.com/destination-page
```

I tested normal 301 redirect code not work, can anyone please help how can I do this?

Comment: If you want to match query string contents, you need to use a RewriteCond.

Comment: Can you please give me code?

Comment: No. Please do research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=this\+is\+source\+link
RewriteRule ^$ http://domainb.com/destination-page? [R=301,L]
```

That will redirect any visit to the homepage with a query string starting with 's=this+is+source+link' to the page you specified. It should go in a .htaccess file in the root of domainA.

**Update Following Discussion in Comments**

To redirect everything with `s=` at the start of the query string, having any value:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=
RewriteRule ^$ http://domainb.com/destination-page? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi thank you, your code is redirecting perfectly but with a small problem, its adding "?s=this is source link" in destination url and giving page not found error, any idea?

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Sorry about that. I updated the code so the query string will now be removed before redirecting (adding a question mark at the end of the redirected URL on the last line). I see you're new to SO. Welcome :) Please use the tick at the top left of my answer to show you accept it and give me some reputation points for it. Thanks!

Comment: Great stuff, glad to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi again, just want your opinion, I have hundreds of link need to redirect, do you suggest me to add all links in htaccess using your code? or is there any way that will redirect all query start with  "?s=" to my destination page, I am asking this because I will need all source link will go same destination page.

Comment: Yes if that works ok for you, just redirect everything with s= in it. I will add code for that.

Comment: It could also be updated to redirecting anything with s= in it anywhere in the query string, if you might get query strings with multiple parameters and s is not the first one.

Comment: Thanks again, its working perfectly, your code save my hours.

Comment: You're most welcome. Thanks. I enjoy working on different mod rewrite problems and helps keep my skills sharp. I learn a lot doing it too.

Comment: Hi Sir can you please help me about this redirect problem also, I posted here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824537/redirect-all-unknown-url-to-another-site